# Query doesn't execute the if statement

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This query doesn't execute the if statement correctly so it doesn't do the else statement even if it should
(it just execute the  'Confirm'  and doesn't execute  'Pass not correct'  even if it should )

```
              StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Invetatons').where('pin',isEqualTo: widget.npasscode)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if (!snapshot.hasData  ) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      var qr = snapshot.data.docs;
                      return ListView.builder (
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          if(qr[index]['pin'] == widget.npasscode){
                              return Text('Confirm');}
                           if(qr[index]['pin'] != widget.npasscode){
                            return Text(' Pass not correct'); }
                          }
                      );
                    }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the query wrong. You are trying to query only those docs where the `pin` is equal to the `widget.npasscode`. Please remove the query and you will get the desired functionality.

```
                              StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Invetatons').where('pin',isEqualTo: widget.npasscode)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (!snapshot.hasData  ) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  var qr = snapshot.data.docs;
                  if(qr.length==0){
                     return Text(' Pass not correct'); 
                  }
                  return ListView.builder (
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      if(qr[index]['pin'] == widget.npasscode){
                          return Text('Confirm');}
                      
                      }
                  );
                }})
```

Comment: I tried this before and it do the if statement serval times according to the number of documents

Comment: I have edited the code in my answer. Try it.